# Repeatively restructure a table excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to create a vba code to rebuild a table with the information fed into it. What the code should do is the following:

Look in column G for the first none empty and non 0 cell and copy that value to the first #N/A in column C. Finally recalculate row for the first cell found in column C.This is the code I have. 
   [image]

```
 i = 3
    For i = 3 To 79
        If Cells(i, 7).Value > 0 And Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then
        MovingValue = Cells(i, 7).Value
        Cells(i, 7).Copy

j = 3
For j = 3 To 4
    If Cells(j, 3).Text = "#N/A" Then Exit For
    Cells(j, 3).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Cells(i, 3).FormulaLocal = "=VLOOKUP(B" & (i) & ";'Cleaning step 2'!B:C;2;0)-" & MovingValue

Next j

End If
Next i
```

What I can't get it to do is, jump out of the code after it has completed this cylce an redo it for a new run. Recheck column G for first non empty and non 0. etc.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the goal? To have Column G be only 0 or blank?